# Run individual cron jobs with Drush

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cron, hook, drush

Is it possible to run individual cron jobs via Drush? e.g. I have a cron job named "mycron". In the Esysia UI I can run that 1 job by clicking [run].

In drush, I can use the command "drush elysia-cron" but that will run all active cron jobs.

My Question: how can I run mycron (only) via drush?

Request: Make all cron jobs available in drush so "drush elysia-cron mycron" would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I am eval'ing my own cron hook.

1) Find the appropriate **hook_cron** call in your module. **modulename_cron** is what you want.

2) Figure out if any specific variables impact when it is run. In my case, there is a variable **modulename_cron_last** which tracks the last time the cron was run. I have to force this to 0 to get it to run.

3) Run drush:

```
drush eval "variable_set('modulename_cron_last', 0);"
drush eval "modulename_cron();"
drush eval "variable_set('modulename_cron_last', time());"
```

**OR**

If you use the 2.x DEV version for D7 this is possibile with command:

```
drush elysia-cron run [JOB_NAME]
or:
drush elysia-cron run [JOB_NAME] --ignore-time
```

(use --ignore-time to force execution)

4) Make a script and add it to your scheduler (in my case, the actual local Linux crontab)

Comment: How do you run an individual cron programmatically with or without using elysia